# Xcode 12 and SVG from a string/text

Tags: swift, xcode, svgkit

I'm trying to manipulate SVG using simple XML codes to add SVG into Xcode using the framework [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit).

But I got a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file aiSoccer/DetailViewController.swift, line 86

**Here is the code:**

```
let dataSvg = "<svg width=\"100\" height=\"100\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"green\" stroke-width=\"4\" fill=\"yellow\" /></svg>".data(using: .utf8)
    
let receivedIcon: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: dataSvg) // LINE 86

self.imageView.image = receivedIcon.uiImage
```

I'm a noob with Xcode/Swift, can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

You can't receive the Icon due to `dataSvg` is nil. You can use `try` for checking the nil as below:

```
     let dataSvg = "<svg width=\"100\" height=\"100\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"green\" stroke-width=\"4\" fill=\"yellow\" /></svg>".data(using: .utf8)
     let data = try? Data(contentsOf: dataSvg)
     let receivedIcon: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: data)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me: I see this error: Fatal error: *Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* on the first line

Comment: I got a different error:  *Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to expected argument type 'URL'*